# How to replace EU driving licence with a UK one when the first one has been lost?

Tags: united-kingdom, france, eu-citizens, driving-license

I am a EU person living in UK.
Lost my driving licence in UK.
How can have it replaced by a UK one ?
How is it possible to prove that I have a driving licence at all?
I can't get a replacement from my country. They told me I need to be resident in France.
Awkward situation.
I am Puzzled!
Any advice?

Comment: Did you exchange your foreign license, then physically lost the UK license paper? Did you physically lose your foreign license paper? Or your permission to drive? 99% that some foreign agency will know that you have say French permission to drive, and either you or DVLA will be able to enquire this.

Comment: Note that driving without the paper proving that you have a license is illegal, but I don’t think anyone asked me to see it in 25 years. In the UK people use it mostly as an identity card.